# Apache rewrite rules with Perl backslash sequences not working

Tags: regex, perl, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one pretty simple rewrite rule working on Nginx:

```
rewrite (*UTF8)^/([\pL\pN\/-]*)$ /index.php?route=$1;
```

It uses Perl backslash sequences to match all unicode letters and numbers.

I tried to reproduce it on Apache:

```
RewriteRule ^([\pL\pN\/-]*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

however it matches only slashes and dashes. Error log is clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` doesn't support `\p` properties but you can use `\w` with `B` and `NE` flag that will send you rewritten URI unescaped to `/index.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)$ /index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L,B,NE]
```

**PS:** `\w` also includes underscore.